# Use SerialPort commands in a Thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-communication

I have a thread, and I want to send some command with Serial Port. How Can I do this?

```
Thread execProcess = new Thread(eProcess);

static bool isRunning = false;

static void eProcess()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(isRunning)
        {
            sendCmd(cmd); //cmd is a string
        }
    }
}

void sendCmd(string cmd)
{
   serialPort.WriteLine(cmd);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There are good MSDN examples about the SerialPort class. So, what is the problem?

Comment: Threads need static functions, and I thing I can set Serial class to static, I did'nt find any solutions.

Comment: Take a look at the constructor, and how to make a new instance of serialport

Comment: "Threads need static functions" - whatever you think this means, it's not true. Bear in mind that *all* code runs on a thread. That one thread is somewhat special in some contexts (e.g. the UI thread) doesn't mean that the main thread isn't as "thready" as any other thread you create.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, were are your information about .NET threads from. See here:

[Thread class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SerialPort class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)